# Microsoft CRM Error Report

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-4

We created a new organization and trying to use it but we are getting below error. Please give some idea how to resolve/dig this issue.

> An unhandled exception occured during the execution of the current web
>   request.Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Error Details: Exception of type 'System.web.HttpUnhandledException'
>   was thrown.

Thanks

Comment: Where's the stack trace?

Comment: please provide steps to recreate this issue (is it when logging on, is it when performing a CRM action like creating a record, is it when going to a specific view)